# Facing Issue while Reading the file in pandas using read_excel()

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read the excel file using read_excel function of pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel(file_path,sheet_name='ABC')

getting Error: "Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'u\xabZj\x9ae\x89\xc6'"
```

This error is coming suddenly, earlier read_excel() working fine.
Can anyone suggest me the solution to this error?

Comment: Are you sure it's an Excel file still and hasn't been changed? Could you post the file path? It might help.

Comment: @Pad yes,100% sure.